# Being g a continuous function show that

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

$$
(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}, \quad x\in \mathbb R
$$
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n+n^2 x & \text{if } x\in\left[-\frac 1 n , 0 \right], \\
n - n^2 x & \text{if } x\in\left[0,\frac 1 n \right], \\
0 & \text{if } x\not\in\left[-\frac 1 n , \frac 1 n \right]. \end{cases}
$$
$$
g(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_n(y-x) \, dx \quad \forall y\in\mathbb R.
$$

Considering a given sequence, $f_n$ is asked to show it is pointwise convergent.
Then considering a continuous function $g(y)$, with $y \in\mathbb R$, it is asked to show that the equality is always true.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure: "se" is "if"? And does "simply convergent" mean "pointwise convergent"?

Comment: yes Daniel Fischer

Comment: The integral is a convolution of $g$ with an approximation to Dirac's delta function (which is in an important sense not really a function).  As $n\to\infty$, the function $f_n$ approaches the delta function $\delta$.  And $g*\delta=g$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what simply convergent is but to show the final limit is true notice:

$$\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f_{n}(x-y)dx- g(y)\rvert=\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}(g(x)-g(y))f_{n}(x-y)dx\rvert$$

$$\le\lvert\int_{y-\frac{1}{n}}^{y+\frac{1}{n}}(g(x)-g(y))f_{n}(x-y)dx\rvert+\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R\setminus[y-\frac{1}{n},y+\frac{1}{n}]}}(g(x)-g(y))f_{n}(x-y)dx\rvert<\epsilon$$

where $n$ is chosen large enough that $\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert<\epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x-y\rvert<\frac{1}{n}$ and notice that $f_{n}(x-y)=0$ outside of $(y-\frac{1}{n},y+\frac{1}{n})$. I also used that the functions $f_{n}$ all integrate to $1$. This can be demonstrated by either taking the time to integrate the function in a piecewise manner or notice that the functions represent a sequence of triangles of increasing height. The base of the triangle has length $\frac{2}{n}$ and height $n$ so the area is $1$ for each $n$. This limit should not be surprising as the $f_{n}$ pointwise converge to the dirac delta.

Comment: i don't understand the way you put g(y) inside the integral and  "n is chosen large enough that ∣g(x)=g(y)∣<ϵ whenever ∣x−y∣<1/n "

Comment: I put the $g(y)$ inside the integral since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x-y)dx=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ so $g(y)=g(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x-y)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(y)f_{n}(x-y)dx$. Since $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then there is $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta$ then $\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert<\epsilon$. Choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so large that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$. Then if $\lvert x-y\rvert<\frac{1}{n}$ then $\lvert g(x)-g(y)\rvert<\epsilon$. I use this estimate when I partition the integral.